# pre-render error when building a next.js app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, deployment, build, pre-rendering

I am trying to build my blog app but it has a problem that I didn't understand. The app works properly when using the command `npm run dev` but when I build it by `npm run build` it gives me a prerender error.

I expected that the app will be built straitly as it does in the "dev" mode. I have tried to follow the instructions in the next.js docs by making the props have default values, and avoid "undefined" by using "null" but it simply didn't work. And I am not using  (output: 'export' or next export).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.